# Nokia Suite backup folders

Tags: backup, nokia-ovi-suite

I have Nokia Suite installed on a Windows XP PC, but now I need to use another one (still with Windows XP), and I need to transfer my content to the new location.

Installing again the program on the new PC is not a problem, but I need to know where the Suite stores the backups of my phone (including SMS, photos, contacts, and so on) in order to transfer them to the new location.

The folder in the "Programs" directory only contains the files needed to run the application, and none of my personal files, and inside "Documents and Settings" I'm unable to find what I need (but I suspect that those files should be somewhere there).

How can I do this?

Comment: While backing up can't you specify a path?

Comment: No, the application syncs automatically with my phone without any prompt. In the Options screen it only allows me to specify a path for photo synchronization, but not for contacts and messages, that are the things I'm most interested in getting out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find some workarounds to backup the data from the Nokia Suite.

I still haven't figured out where it stores all the data, but here is how I did to back it up (note that I have the Italian version installed, so what I type might differ a bit from the English version).

- For images and videos, I selected in the menu *Tools* → *Options* → *gallery*, here it is possible to see which folder is used to backup these items, and change it if desired.
- For music, similarly, I went to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Music*. The same story here.
- For contacts, from the main program window I went into the `Contacts` tab, and from there, selected menu *File* → *Export Contacts*. Note that this will only export the currently selected contacts in the list, so to backup all of them, I first had to select the whole list; this way, the contacts are saved in `.vcf` format, so they are accessible also from other applications, if desired. To import them back in the new installation, I went to menu *File* → *import contacts*. As simple as it sounds.
- For messages, the procedure was similar to contacts. From the main windows, went to the `messages` tab and selected menu *File* → *Export all SMS*. This command exports all messages stored in the program in `.csv` format, so, again, they are accessible also by other software; to import them back, menu *File* → *Import SMS*.